# Science fiction carton/animated short: robot spider/insect crash lands and kills a superhero

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, short-film

I'm looking for an old cartoon that I watched back in like the early 90s. Not sure when it was made, but it was a short for sure.

It was about an alien robot insect/spider? that crash lands somewhere in an urban environment. There was a superhero that was killed by it, an a kid ended up climbing up on it, opening the hatch and saw a cockroach/insect of some sort operating it.

The kid just smashes it with his fist.

I know there were more animated shorts that followed it.

Answer (score 13):

Sounds like the "Grinning Evil Death" short ([Bob Sabiston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Sabiston), 1990) that I first saw on Season 1, Episode 1 of MTV's *[Liquid Television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_Television)*.

Comment: Yes it is thanks

Comment: @Anthony If this is correct, please mark it as correct by clicking the green tick box next to the answer. Thanks!